# Unscale subsetted data in R by subsets

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, normalization, denormalization

I have the following data from a marketing campaign

```
 SegmentPriority    MarketingLInkClicked    Campaigntype    ProductSeries
    Low             184.00                  Promotional       A
  Medium            249.00                  Promotional         A
  Medium            0.00                     Promotional        A
   High             10.00                    Resale             B
  Medium           48.00                     Resale             B
    Low             9.00                 Promotional         Misc
   Medium           94.00                Promotional            C
   Medium           318.00                  Promotional         C
    Medium          156.00               Promotional            D
    Medium          67.00                 Resale                 D
    High             3.00                  Buyback               C
    High             622.00                 Buyback              C
```

I have subsetted the datframe to scale the values given in the second column using dplyr. The subsetting is by means of the campaigntype, segment priority and product series. I would like to convert the predicted values to their original form.  I am doing the same manually.

How can I do the same by means of a loop/ package

Note: I used the following code to subset the data and scale the same

```
   df %>%
  group_by(SegmentPriority,Campaigntype, ProductSeries) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(scale), MarketingLInkClicked)
```

This is supposed to generate a scaled version of the variable that is subsetted.

Comment: Have a look at `group_by`, `do` and maybe `summarise` of the package `dplyr`. From a statistics viewpoint: maybe a mixed model with random slopes is more suitable than scaling every observation groupwise.

Comment: I have used groupby and summarise already Sir, but to scale the date. To get back the originials, we need to use unscale.

Comment: Mixed model with Random Slopes sounds attractive but can it be used for a decision tree based model.Please let me know

Comment: Unscaling the data is not possible, you loose neccessary information when you scale. Unless you saved the mean and standard deviation of the data before scaling you cannot undo it.